# Angular JSON Parse

Tags: angularjs, json

OK, I'm stumped. I have an angular json GET process that is pulling results in as expected but I can't seem to parse and get to individual values of the result.

Here is the string result I'm getting:

```
{"result":[{"sys_id":"f4425c21ec0970407e85e2a57ceff437","number":"INC0035062"}]}
```

And here is my code:

```
$http({
 method:'GET',
 url:$scope.url,
 transformResponse: undefined}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function(response) {
  console.error('Error', response.status, response.data);
})
.finally(function() {
  console.log("All Done");
});
```

SO, how can I get to an individual value of a sys_id?

Thanks in advance,
DP

*******EDIT:
Sajeetharan, still having an issue. Changed code per your example:

```
console.log(response.data);
  $scope.data = response.data.result; 
  console.log($scope.data);
  console.log("Sys id is:"+$scope.data[0].sys_id);
```

Output:

```
{"result":[{"sys_id":"f4425c21ec0970407e85e2a57ceff437","number":"INC0035062"}]}
undefined
TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference
   at Anonymous function (******.EvScripts.jsdbx:59:3)
   at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:130:399)
   at m.prototype.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:145:96)
   at m.prototype.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:142:165)
   at m.prototype.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:145:399)
   at l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:97:248)
   at K (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:101:373)
   at y.onload (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:102:397)
Error undefined undefined
```

Comment: Where does your url points to? My guess is your response does not contain application/json content tyoe header, so angullar does not automatically parses it

Comment: It points to the incident table on my ServiceNow instance. I did set the header as such: 
$http.defaults.headers.common.Accept = "application/json";

Comment: The `Accept` header is for server use, that is the client "says" the server which formats are acceptable. The server should respond with the proper `Content-Type` header. So the header that you've set, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working, via angular.fromJson:

```
//CALL TO REST SERVICES
//---------------------
$http({
 method:'GET',
 url:$scope.url,
 transformResponse: undefined}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.data);
  $scope.data = angular.fromJson(response.data); 
  console.log($scope.data['result'][0].sys_id);
}).catch(function(response) {
  console.error('Error', response.status, response.data);
})
.finally(function() {
  console.log("All Done");
});
//---------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access sys_id, access the **`0th index`**  of the array **`data`**,

```
 $http.get('test.json').then(function(response){
      $scope.data = response.data.result;      
  });
```

If you want to access the sys_id using expression,

**In Html**

```
 <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
   <h1> Sys id is :{{data[0].sys_id}} </h1>
  </div>
```

If you want to access the sys_id using controller,

```
$http.get('test.json').then(function(response){
          $scope.data = response.data.result; 
          console.log("Sys id is:"+$scope.data[0].sys_id);     
      });
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/gXLvcTHG2cqgOtPFPTRA?p=preview)**